# Getting warning like Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged

Tags: ios, objective-c

When I'm trying  to select images from camera rolls, I'm getting the following warning. (when I press the button camera rolls it goes to select albums page where we can select images from our phone).

> Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is
>   discouraged

My `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method is like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {


    [application setStatusBarHidden:YES];
    NSUserDefaults *userDefault = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [userDefault synchronize];

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *navigation = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
    self.window.rootViewController = navigation;
    navigation.navigationBarHidden = YES;

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

My camera button code is:

```
- (void)cameraButtonSelected
{

ELCAlbumPickerController *albumController = [[ELCAlbumPickerController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
ELCImagePickerController *elcPicker = [[ELCImagePickerController alloc] initWithRootViewController:albumController];
[albumController setParent:elcPicker];
[elcPicker setDelegate:self];

AppDelegate *app = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

[app.viewController presentViewController:elcPicker animated:YES completion:nil];
[self.view.window.rootViewController.navigationController pushViewController:elcPicker animated:YES];
   }
```

Comment: At first, Please format your snippet in well manner.

Comment: Where is your code of selecting image from camera rolls ?

Comment: Yeah, here i added code for camera method pls check it once...

Answer (score 0):

In your ViewController or ViewDidAppear method write your camera method.

Comment: Yeah i wrote camera method in view did load method of view controller.

Answer (score 0):

Here, you are trying to present `picker` as well as push , both at a time.

Either push your picker or present it.

And if you are present or push it from any view controller then just write :

Either

```
[self presentViewController:elcPicker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Or

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:elcPicker animated:YES];
```

Comment: If possible, then use built in class `UIImagePickerController`